# Turtle graphics stopped working after installing Anaconda-navigator version 1.9.7

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda

I am using `macOS Mojave 10.14.6` and `Python 3.7.3`.  I was running some turtle programs which then worked.  Subsequently, I installed `anaconda-navigator 1.9.7`.  After which, if I ran a turtle program such as below, I would get a blank screen (black) for a few seconds, after which I would be logged out.

```
# SquareSpiral1.py - Draws a square spiral
import time    
import turtle    
t = turtle.Pen()    
t.pencolor('green')    
for x in range(50):    
      t.forward(x)    
      t.left(90)       
time.sleep(30)  # sleep for 30 seconds
```

Is there any way to make turtle graphics work with anaconda-navigator?